# Converting a JSON into a Model Value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

In my quest to learn more about Swift, I'm looking at ways to improve my app and noticed a few places where I'm making assumptions where perhaps I shouldn't be.

When creating a new object, lets say a 'student', they need things like a name (`String`), age (`Int`) and score (`Float`). I read these from a `JSON` file, and put them into an object like this:

```
// note, details is a [String:Any] type
let name = details["name"] as! String
let age = details["age"] as! Int 
let score = Float(details["score"])
self.student = Student(name: name, tutor_group: tutor_group, score: score)
```

So my questions are as follows;
1. How should I modify my code to check that if a value is not a number, where it should be, the variable becomes just `nil`, or even better 0?
2. What if the key in the dictionary doesn't exist?
3. Are the different ways to do this, and if so, which is best practice?

**Note** that I want to keep this code as short as possible - `if`/`else` statements for each line are not what I'm looking for.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: When it comes to programming, on a general basis 'safe' and 'quick' do not mesh well together.

Comment: If you are reading the data from a **file** you are supposed to know if a key exists and what type the values are. In other words, check the contents of the file at compile time to be safe at runtime. By the way this makes the code as short as possible.

Comment: It depends a little upon how the JSON, itself, is formatted. Notable, these numeric values should not be strings, but rather should be numbers without quotes. Then `NSJSONSerialization` will do some of the conversion for you. E.g. you should have `{"name": "Bob", "age": 29, "score": 29042.3}`.

Comment: If an item that should be a number is not a number, then nil is exactly the right value, not 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The Solution suggested by the Swift team

Recently Apple [described](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) the suggested way to face this problem.

You can define the `Student` struct (or class) this way

```
struct Student {

    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let score: Float

    init?(json: [String:Any]) {
        guard
            let name = json["name"] as? String,
            let age = json["age"] as? Int,
            let score = json["score"] as? Float
            else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.score = score
    }
}
```

### Benefits of this approach

1. You **encapsulate** the logic to convert a JSON into a `Student` inside the `Student` struct itself
2. If the `JSON` doesn't contain a valid data (e.g. there is no `age` field with a valid `Int`) then the initializer fails and returns `nil`. This means there is no way to create a `Student` with missing fields (and this is a good thing) and this scenario will not cause a crash.

### More

The post I linked above also describes a more advanced approach where a missing field/value throws an exception. However if you don't need to log (or notify to the caller) why the initialization failed you don't need this.

Comment: I am really really thankful they created an official documentation for this. Creating model objects this way is the most sensible approach.

Comment: @Sulthan: I believed the official approach described by Apple is perfectly consistent with the Swift philosophy.

Comment: Of course it is but they never documented it so clearly. There are still many programmers that leave they data as JSONs all the time, implementing search operations over JSONs, modifying nested JSONs etc.

Comment: @Sulthan: Yes I agree :)

Answer (score 4):

> So my questions are as follows; 1. How should I modify my code to check that if a value is not a number, where it should be, the variable becomes just nil, or even better 0? 2. What if the key in the dictionary doesn't exist? 3. Are the different ways to do this, and if so, which is best practice?

```
let age = (details["age"] as? Int) ?? 0
```

- In all cases, `age` will have the type `Int`
- If the key doesn't exist, `details["age"]` will return `nil`, `as? Int` will return an `Int?` with value `nil` and the *nil coalescing operator* `??` will set the value to `0`.
- If the type isn't an `Int`, the conditional cast `as? Int` will return `nil` and the value will be set to `0`.
- In the expected case, `age` will have the `Int` value that was stored in `details["age"]`.

---

For the other fields:

```
let name = (details["name"] as? String) ?? ""

// If score is stored as a String
let score = Float(details["score"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0
```

OR

```
// If score is stored as a number
let score = (details["score"] as? Float) ?? 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use guard instead:

```
guard let name = details["name"] as? String else {
   return
}
print("\(name)")
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may not want to bail so early, instead it is possible that the OP wants to provide a default parameter value.

Comment: In that case, we can use `Nil coalescing` operator to assign any default value to the object.

`let name = (details["name"] as? String) ?? "" `